# android: google play promotion code for inapp billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, promotion-code

I have used a promotioncode to buy an in-app product during tests of my app for its in-app product purchase flow.

Although promotion code is detected, my application cannot detect it as purchased.
This is like this: inside implementation of `IAbHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener` I have this method:

```
@Override
public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
    ...
    ...
    Purchase activationPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_ACTIVATION);
    boolean activated = (activationPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(activationPurchase));
}
```

However my `activationPurchase` read from google play is something like this:
    PurchaseInfo(type:inapp):
    {
    "packageName":"my.package.name",
     "productId":"activation",
     "purchaseTime":1471991353652,
     "purchaseState":0,
     "purchaseToken":"a-real-token"
     }

And as you see in picture from application watch, developer payload is shown as empty string "", so purchase is not validated and purchaseState is `0`.
So the question is how can I detect this product is bought using REDEEM CODE?
[image]

Comment: I have same problem. go purchase object now how to verify the signature using google play store